# Excel 2016 crashes when using Debug.Print Tab() in Workbook_Open() event handler

Tags: vba, excel, events, crash, excel-2016

Just something weird I noticed, tested on 2 computers with similar config (Windows 10 64-bit up-to-date with Excel 2016 32-bit), one was a clean install :

Simply create a new .xlsm workbook, and place the following in the ThisWorkbook.cls class module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Debug.Print Tab(10); "Hello!"
End Sub
```

Save. Close. Open (if opens in PROTECTED VIEW mode, Enable editing, close and re-open). Excel crashes.

Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example.

Now the big question: why?

I tried to delay the problematic `Debug.Print Tab(10); "Hello!"` by placing it in a Sub which I call a few sec after the Open event with `Application.OnTime Now() + (1/3600/24) * 5, "SubName"`, still crashing. I call it manually, it works just fine.

MSDN says nothing about it: [Tab Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/tab-function?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Edit 19/04/2021

First, I have to say that I am a bit stunned : I asked this question on Apr 19 '18 at 7:42 (2018-04-19 07:42:36Z). There was not at this time, and there still is not, any reference to this bug on Stack Overflow. I have not encountered this bug since. And today, exactly 3 yers later to the day, I stumbled on it again. Fate is quite amazing.

Anyway, it appears this bug occurs as soon as a single `Tab` character is attempted to be printed in the VBE Immediate window with the `Debug.Print` and method without the VBE window loaded (meaning not opened once in the current Excel instance). That's why it was easier encountering it during an Workbook_Open event... But if you place the following sub in a workbook, close it, and run it from the Developper tab > Macro button without opening the VBE, Excel will also crash:

```
Private Sub test_MRE()
    Debug.Print Tab
End Sub
```

So one must be very careful not to send Empty variables to the console (or you will probably look for hours before finding out what's happening, speaking knowingly...), because this will also cause Excel to crash (the `,` being a `Tab` and noting being sent before it):

```
Private Sub test_MRE()
    Dim Var1 'Variant/Empty
    Debug.Print Var1, "hello"
End Sub
```

I managed in my project to make the error we can hear before Excel crashes to appear, and it is an Automation Error, if it helps someone to better understand what's really happening:

[image: automation error]

Comment: Works on Win7/Office 2010, but crashes on Win10/Office 2016. However, if I put an empty `Debug.Print` as first statement, it works.

Comment: indeed, no more crash! fine idea you had :)

Comment: also crash on Windows 10/Office 2007